# Tab Bar Controller - Show a view controller that is not one of the tabs

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I wonder if this is possible. The design for this app I am working on is as below:

Two sliding views sit one on top of the other. The bottom view is a 'Settings' view. The top view is a tab bar view. We are using [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController) for the sliding.

1. When the app is opened for the first time, the tab bar view shows with first tab selected.
   [image]
2. When they tap on the hamburger menu or slide right, the bottom, settings view slides into view.
   [image: Mockup 2]
3. When they tap on an item in the settings view, like the About item, the corresponding view should be displayed inside the top tab bar view with none of the tabs shown as selected.
   [image: Mockup 3]

I think I am going to have to convince my team to not display the settings items inside of the tab bar, it seems just too twisted. But just wanted to know if anyone else has done anything like this and if it is possible to do it without introducing too much complication in the code.

Comment: Try presenting it as modal. The best way. If you need code help, I seek some time.

Comment: Were you able to perform this or stuck between some thing in between ?

Comment: The fact that it's difficult to explain, and difficult to implement, should set your spidey sense tingling. What you're doing is breaking the navigation hierarchy that you are presenting to your user. The reason it's hard to implement is that it's a terrible idea in the first place. The 'correct' solution would be to present the view within the sidebar (although that doesn't necessarily mean that's a good idea either). — I write this realizing that it's 1 year since the OP, but figured someone might benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something with the same design with a menu that slides from the left and over the tab bars. I ended up putting a View Controller on top of everything else

Something like

```
[self presentViewController:AboutViewController Animated:YES];
```

Just make sure that you either put that view controller in a UINavigationController or something with a `dismissViewController` for users to return to your main page.